# Memory usage goes up after I kill another user session

Tags: xubuntu, ram

I've killed a user session to free some memory, but memory usage increased. How is that possible?

```
user2@somehostname:~$ who -u
user1 :0           2018-05-26 13:58   ?          1249 (:0)
user2     pts/0        2018-05-29 09:09   .         13442 (:10.0)
user2@somehostname:~$ free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           991        500        490         20         10        200
-/+ buffers/cache:        289        701
Swap:         1952        225       1727
$ sudo kill  1249
$ who -u
user2      pts/0        2018-05-29 09:09   .         13442 (:10.0)
user2@somehostname:~$ free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           991        582        408         40         17        252
-/+ buffers/cache:        312        678
Swap:         1952        167       1785
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run commands one after another or gave OS some time to settle? Memory usage should spike but then decrease because IS runs cleanup processes. That’s what it looks like.

Did you wait for too long (OS might have started a background task)? Did you run any apps after kill but before free -m?